# How and why could leak period detect an old issue as new for msbuild

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are having an issue with SonarQube analysis where known issues are failing the quality gate.  This is an existing code base, after initial analysis, existing issues should remain as is and new code is analyzed.   Thus if a developer checks in code, I would expect only new changes are analyzed and scanned.  However, SonarQube is detecting both new changes and existing changes as issues during the leak period.

How does Sonar determine the differences between current and previous for the leak period?  Is it purely analyzing source files or is there something else happening?  What could cause existing code to cause a new issue in the leak period?  I'm trying to determine how to diagnose and troubleshoot this issue.

Running:
SonarQube 7.1
sonar-scanner-msbuild  4.2.0.1214
TFS 2012
4 TFS 2012 Build Agents
No SCM integration

Edit:
I mostly see these issues in Bugs and Code Smells.  The leak period is based on the previous run, versions are not being used.  It seems to be more problematic with SonarQube 7.1 than with the previous 6.7.  Here is an example flow that happened:

1) Initial Sonar Analyzes/Scan -- All code is green
2) New check-in  -- All code is green
3) New check-in, one line change -- all previously "green" items from step 1 are flagged and gate fails

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details about an example issue: issue type, date of last modification of the line the issue is raised on, (anything else that seems relevant), and also include some details about your leak period: is it date based, version based, ...? How long ago did it start? And so on...

Comment: I updated the question, not sure of what else you would need.  I'm trying to figure out if there is something wrong with how builds are setup or something in our environment.  I do not know enough about how the leak period works.